# NativeScript Angular HttpClient generic get method returns object instead Typed object

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

Im trying to use: `this.httpClient.get<MyObject>(myUrl)`to retrieve object serialized in Json response. Intellisense accept this object but if i look into debug console what exact service return to me it is still only object. Class for MyObject is declared like this:

```
export class MyObject {
  public id:String
  public value:String
  public toString():String {
    return this.value;  
  }
}
```

The returned object form `httpClient.get` has all variables (id, value) but has no method `toString`. I know that there is possibility to write map method to create object of class MyObject "by hand", but i thing this is lot of unnecessary work when I have many services and many object returned from them. Is there any other possibility to has real MyObject instance returned from HttpClient?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any other possibility

No.

HttpClient doesn't know and care about your classes. All it does to transform the JSON response body into objects is `JSON.parse()`. And that returns a POJO, not an instance of `MyObject`. If you really want an instance of `MyObject`, then you need to transform the POJO into a `MyObject`.